# style each div with a different color using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a home page with `ul li div` the div is a square box and i have 3x3 at the top.
The bottom section of my site is code generated mark up and i have something similar.

I would like to give each div "box" a color, currently they are all styled with css. Is there a way with jquery to check for ul li div and if the div exists then add a DIFFERENT colour to the inline style? I would need to store the colors in the script.

This is how i could start?:

```
$("div.box").css({"background-color": "color"});
```

Here is my example cut down markup:

```
<ul>
<li data-target="aboutme" data-target-activation="click" style="margin-top:0px" class="tile high me">
          <div>
          <h2>About Me</h2>
        <h3></h3>
         <img width="48" height="48" alt="" class="icon" src="images/icons/x.png">
     </div>
</li>

<li data-target="aboutme" data-target-activation="click" style="margin-top:0px" class="tile high me">
          <div>
          <h2>Pane 2</h2>
        <h3></h3>
         <img width="48" height="48" alt="" class="icon" src="images/icons/x.png">
     </div>
</li>

<li data-target="aboutme" data-target-activation="click" style="margin-top:0px" class="tile high me">
          <div>
          <h2>Pane 3</h2>
        <h3></h3>
         <img width="48" height="48" alt="" class="icon" src="images/icons/x.png">
     </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is the css:

```
       .tiles {
        height: 95%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-height: 950px;
        overflow: visible;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 957px;
    }

    .tile.high {
    float: left;
        height: 200px;
        margin-top: -100px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 23.6%;
    }

    li.tile div {
        background-color: #00ABA9;
    }

    .tile div {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 10px 10px 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;

    }
```

Comment: how about you share your markup?

Comment: here you go something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k6TqC/

Comment: added the ul (opps) - http://jsfiddle.net/k6TqC/2/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Loop through div's and use different color on each:

```
// Declare colors you want to use
var myColors = [
    '#f00', '#abc', '#123'
];
var i = 0;
$('div.box').each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', myColors[i]);
    i = (i + 1) % myColors.length;
});
```

Check online: http://jsfiddle.net/4NVRQ/

Comment: This looks good, I have added my example markup. But its not changing the color? the color is assigned to: `li.tile div`

Comment: i have to award you with the marked answer as you met the requirement of assigning colours to the script.

Comment: I am late but i need this. What if i want to change background-color on hover too?

Answer (score 1):

```
var 

color = function(){
    return '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
},
$els = $('div.box'),
colorify = function(els){
    els.each(function(){
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', color());
    });
};

colorify($els);
```

Comment: i have added some mark up, so this add a random color to the div.box?

Comment: yeah this generates a random color and `colorify` takes a jQuery collection of elements. So just replace `$els` with the elements you want to affect, and call `colorify`

Comment: sweeet, the power of random!!

Comment: The power of Google actually... http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/

Comment: I have to award the answer as marked completed. But this example is probably very useful to, wish we could accept 2 answers. :( thanks